# Как работают бэкенд и фронтенд части принцип

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, frontend, backend

Есть заготовка проекта на vue js там весь фронт.

Нужно создать бекенд на node js (который, по-сути не будет в самом себе хранить данные, а будет их получать по реализованному апи  от отдельной машины с БД).

Как правильно должно происходить взаимодействие, нода слушает запросы от фронта и выдаёт данные в ответе? Бек и фронт должны находится в одной среде разработки (ИДЕ) и в одном проекте или должны быть абсолютно друг от друга не зависящие части на разных машинах.?

Comment: Почему в таком случае нельзя сразу с vue.js слать запрос по API с БД?

Comment: напрямую, из фронта тянуть данные по апи не желательно, потому что тот апи будет постоянно меняться, и нужен слой прокладка, который будет с этим работать и подсраиваться под него. Получается, фронт - (ничего не меняется) - бек - (постоянные изменения структуры) - АПИ - (постоянные изменения структуры) - БД

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если позволяют возможности то идеальный вариант - 3 независимых приложения, общающихся друг с другом по АПИ

1. Фронт на Vue.js который отправляет запросы посреднику
2. Посредник - написанный Вами на node.js, который будет как маршрутизатор, и будет лезть за инфой к поставщику, а так же будет содержать всю бизнес-логику
3. Поставщик - любой сторонний сервис, откуда получаются данные